# setOnBindEditTextListener in preferenceEditTextnot found

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences

I was trying to use **setOnBindEditTextListener** to **EditTextPreference**, but it says that it cannot resolve the method. Where is the problem?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.EditText;



import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

import static com.chemistryApps.Constants.NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS_GUESS_FORMULA;
import static com.chemistryApps.Constants.NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS_GUESS_NAME;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

private SettingsFragment.OnPreferenceInteractionListener mListener;

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general,rootKey );

    EditTextPreference preference =
            (EditTextPreference) this.findPreference("first_question");

    preference.setOnBindEditTextListener(new EditTextPreference.OnBindEditTextListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBindEditText(@NonNull EditText editText) {
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed up that I needed to implement the preference library from android separately. Even though all other Preference methods worked.

```
 implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preference_version"
```